# FetchXml on Dynamics doesnt work on a specific user?

Tags: xml, return, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml

I've been struggling with a basic fetch and an inner join.

I've tried the following:

- In the XRMtool FetchXML tester: the fetch works perfectly fine with some non-admin users, but not with others who have the same role as those that work.
- I usually take the condition values from the form, and my intention is to create a custom view depending on the user. So, I tried hardcoding the values, but with some users, it returns data, and with others, it returns `<resultset morerecords="0" />`.
- I tried giving an administrator role to one user, and that fixed their problem, but some users cannot be fixed that way.

Any help would be appreciated.

```xml
    <fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true' > 
        <entity name='new_categorias' > 
            <attribute name='new_name' /> 
            <attribute name='new_codigo' /> 
            <attribute name='new_categoriasid' /> 
            <order attribute='new_name' descending='false' /> 
            <link-entity name='new_conveniounitarios' from='new_categoria' to='new_categoriasid' link-type='inner' alias='ab' > 
                <filter type='and' > 
                    <condition attribute='new_fechainicio' operator='on-or-after' value='2023-01-01' /> 
                    <condition attribute='new_fechainicio' operator='on-or-before' value='2023-12-31' /> 
                    <condition attribute='new_convenio' operator='eq' uitype='new_convenios' value='XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX' /> 
                </filter> 
            </link-entity> 
        </entity> 
    </fetch>
```

Comment: Your fetch seems ok (except the GUID). The question is not 100% clear, but if the same fetch is yielding two different results for different users it is because of security roles or privileges assigned.  if the roles are same possibly different BU. When you say some users cannot be fixed that way, means even with system admin privilege it doesnt work?

Comment: Hi @Harinarayanan, the roles are the same in both users, and even with the admin role doesnt work in some users

Comment: Hey, this cant be the case, same fetch for users with same roles cant fetch different data unless the users are from different Business unit or the fetch are executed against different environments.

Comment: @Harinarayanan it is and i discovered the error, the user local date was set on UTC and mine in UTC+1, the date from the fetch failed becouse the register from dynamics was 1 day before for that 1 hour less and in some users work or doesnt if they change this hour on properties, ty for the help <3

Comment: May be you can add your comment as answer and close the question so it can help out others, I didnt see the datetime in the fetch, good catch.